# p:dialog not able to populate values

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Have made an ajax call to  method which sets the  String value in the bean.

```
 var url = contextPath+'/SlCustomObjectCalls?stCallType=attachmentList&stMandDocumentName='+stMandDocumentName;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        dlg1.show();
    }
});
```

This sets the value in the String [] attachmentList.

```
public class AttachmentViewHelper {

String[] attachmentList;

public String[] getAttachmentList() {
    return attachmentList;
}
public void setAttachmentList(String[] attachmentList) {
    this.attachmentList = attachmentList;
}
public void getAttachments(){

    try {
        String stDocCode = "someval";
        String stProcCode = ""; 
        String stDocNumber ="";
        String stComapny = "";

          // gets String []
        attachmentList = getListOfAttahments(stDocCode);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

and on  success  ajax  opens  the dialog box, where i  want to display the values of the attachment list.

```
<p:dialog id="downloadAttachemntDiag" header="Download" widgetVar="dlg1" width="300" height="200" resizable="false" draggable="false"
                    modal="true">
 <div id="attachment">#{AttachmentViewHelper.attachmentList}</div>
```

Now the problem that I am facing is, the dialog box  does not show any value.
Have tried using **c:foreach** and **ui:repeat**,But it didnt work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would not use ajax function to do a post. You can do it with plain primefaces + jsf.

Comment: Primefaces provide multiple ways to option dialog, why core ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the ajax call you did. 
However one thing I know is that your dialog is initially sent with an empty list an never updated.

So since I don't really know vanilla ajax in jsf you could use the [ajax](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) tag or the update attribute of primefaces.

```
<p:commandButton ... update="downloadAttachemntDiag"/>
```

Comment: Dropped down the idea of using ajax, It worked with remotecommand.